# 'like'keyword in NED language

Tags: omnet++

Hi can anyone tell me the use of 'like' keyword in NED Language. And how does it exactly work.
I was trying to understand castalia code and found this:

```
simple ValueReporting like node.application.iApplication {
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Like` is used to define 'interfaces' that describe how a module looks like from the outside (i.e. you can define the number and name of gates in an interface). Modules can implement an interface using the like keyword (using the syntax in your question).

The advantage of this is, that when you use this interface in any other compound module, you don't have to specify the exact type of the module. Later you can drop into that place any module that implements the given interface (because from the outside, that module looks exactly the same as the interface itself).

Still, the best place to look for information is the OMNeT++ manual: https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ned-lang:submodule-like